# How do I count the number of times an item appears in a column in a datatable in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, count

I have created a datatable with two columns, "Function" and "Date". This table records the date that each of n functions is used on a website. I want to extract the number of times that a particular function such as "Access" appears in the table. Any help will be appreciated.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Function", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(datetime));

table.Rows.Add(Access, 01/08/2012);
table.Rows.Add(Load, 01/08/2012);
table.Rows.Add(Save, 01/08/2012);
table.Rows.Add(Access, 02/08/2012);
table.Rows.Add(Print, 02/08/2012);

int accessCount = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    if (row["Function"] == "Access")
    {
        accessCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: linq is good for that sort of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-Datatable` and `Enumerable.GroupBy` to group by your function. Then you can use [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) to build a dictionary with the function as key and the count as value:

```
var functionLookup = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Function"))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

int accessCount = functionLookup["Access"];  // 2
```

Note that it's case sensitive by default. If you want it to be case insensitive you would need to pass the appropriate `IEqualityComparer` for the key, in this case:

```
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Function"))
    .Select(group => new 
    {
        Function = group.Key,
        Count = group.Count(),
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I get the following error System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @DavidMuller You need to add `using System.Linq` to use the LINQ extension methods.

Comment: Thanks, this looks right in visual studio, but when I try running it i get a different error. "The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' " - this is a separate issue but if you have any suggestions? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for it

```
var result = from rec in table.AsEnumerable 
             group rec by rec.Field<string>("Function") into g 
             select new { Function = g.Key, Count = g.Count()}
```